# Python. Updating value matching on a list

Tags: python

I have a column (row["MenuItemId"]) which contains certain numbers. If the values in that particular location matches values in another list, I want a new column to be created. So I would like to create a list that has the values {45, 46 & 47} and amend the following code and replace it with the name of the list:

> This is my Current Code

```
if row["MenuItemId"] == 45 or row["MenuItemId"] == 46 or row["MenuItemId"] == 47:
            DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"]= 1
else:
            DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"]= 0
```

> Intended Output

---

```
 MenuItemId   beef  
      45      1  
      55      0  
      46      1  
      46      1
```

How do I change the current code so that rather then manually specifiying the numbers with an "or" statement, if the location matches with any item in the list the corresponding value is updated :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```py
allow = [45, 46, 47] # In this list are values, what determine condition. You can pretty good manipulate them :)

if row["MenuItemId"] in allow: # If <value> in <array> is standard for python.
            DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"]= 1
else:
            DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"]= 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test that a number lies within a continuous range of integers, using an inequality expression like this is the best way:

```
if 45 <= row["MenuItemId"] <= 47:
            DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"] = 1
else:
            DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"] = 0
```

You can even reduce this to a single line, as `True` and `False` can be converted to `1` and `0` respectively.

```
DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"] = int(45 < = row["MenuItemId"] <= 47)
```

If the range being tested is not continuous, you can place the values in a list and test for membership of the list:

```
DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"] = int(row["MenuItemId"] in [45, 46, 47, 50])
```

However, if you are going to re-use the non-continuous range, it's more efficient to define it once as a set.

```
beefy = set([45, 46, 47, 50])
DfOrders.loc[x,"beef"] = int(row["MenuItemId"] in beefy)
```

This is because the time taken to find an element in a list, in the worst case, is proportional to the size of the list, but finding an element in a set takes the same time regardless of the size of the set (formally speaking, worst case lookup for a list is *linear time* or O(n), where n is the size of the list, but set lookup time is *constant time*, or O(1)).

If your code only uses the range once you may as well use the list, because Python would have to read through each element to make the set anyway.